# How to improve and apply DRY principle to see if a company is busy or available, depending on the user request?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to develop code which its principal function is to know if a company is available or not when a user starts a new request. In this example I only have 3 requests but it could more.

Also in this example I'm setting the max client per request as 2. That's why I'm doing a lot of `if` validations in the #4 `for` loop. If I set a `max_client = 3`, the If validations pattern must be changed.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

branch_schedule = np.arange('2005-02-01T00:00:00', '2005-02-01T12:00:00', dtype='datetime64[h]')
service_1 = np.arange('2005-02-01T01:00:00', '2005-02-01T02:00:00', dtype='datetime64[h]')
service_2 = np.arange('2005-02-01T03:00:00', '2005-02-01T04:00:00', dtype='datetime64[h]')
service_3 = np.arange('2005-02-01T03:00:00', '2005-02-01T04:00:00', dtype='datetime64[h]')

status_list = []
status_list2 = []
status_list3 = []

for i in range(len(branch_schedule)):
  status = branch_schedule[i] == service_1
  status_list.append(status[0])

for i in range(len(branch_schedule)):
  status = branch_schedule[i] == service_2
  status_list2.append(status[0])

for i in range(len(branch_schedule)):
  status = branch_schedule[i] == service_3
  status_list3.append(status[0])

request_status = []

for i in range(len(status_list)):
  x = status_list[i]
  y = status_list2[i]
  z = status_list3[i]

  if x == False and y == False and z == False:
    r_status = False
    request_status.append(r_status)
  elif x == True and y == False and z == False:
    r_status = False
    request_status.append(r_status)
  elif x == True and y == True and z == False:
    r_status = True
    request_status.append(r_status)
  elif x == True and y == True and z == True:
    r_status = True
    request_status.append(r_status)
    #Poner exepcion Donde Z = True pasarlo a False
  elif x == False and y == True and z == True:
    r_status = True
    request_status.append(r_status)
  elif x == False and y == True and z == False:
    r_status = False
    request_status.append(r_status)
  elif x == True and y == False and z == True:
    r_status = True
    request_status.append(r_status)
  elif x == False and y == False and z == True:
    r_status = False
    request_status.append(r_status)

request_status2 = []

for i in range(len(request_status)):
  if request_status[i] == False:
    r_status2 = 'Disponible: '+ np.datetime_as_string(branch_schedule[i], unit='h')
    request_status2.append(r_status2)
  else:
    r_status2 = 'Ocupado: '+ np.datetime_as_string(branch_schedule[i], unit='h')
    request_status2.append(r_status2)

print(request_status2)
```

Output:

```
['Disponible: 2005-02-01T00', 'Disponible: 2005-02-01T01', 'Disponible: 2005-02-01T02',
 'Ocupado: 2005-02-01T03', 'Disponible: 2005-02-01T04', 'Disponible: 2005-02-01T05',
 'Disponible: 2005-02-01T06', 'Disponible: 2005-02-01T07', 'Disponible: 2005-02-01T08',
 'Disponible: 2005-02-01T09', 'Disponible: 2005-02-01T10', 'Disponible: 2005-02-01T11']
```

Comment: Look for repititive code blocks and ask yourself if they could be put in a function and sent parameters.

Comment: If the code and example is working, and your focus is on coding style, Code Review might be better board.  SO is more for debugging, not review of working code.